# Can I edit my HTML tag via CSS or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, tags

I have a website on Squarespace and unfortunately the backend won't allow me to set a specific language for certain pages which are written in Italian.

I have the chance to make code injections in the header, or make custom CSS rules.

So... can I edit the **lang** attribute of a certain page  tag?

If so, how to point to that specific page HTML tag, if I the only unique class identifying that page is stored in the **body** tag?

Thank you lads!

Answer (score 2):

If you know which tag you want to target, then of course you can:

```
document.querySelector('#myId').lang = "it";
```

---

> If so, how to point to that specific page HTML tag, if I the only unique class identifying that page is stored in the tag?

I don't quite understand what that means, so if this doesn't help you, please explain.

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped "body" and it didn't appear. Now I corrected it.

Comment: Unfortunately, the console states that
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: Well, you don't need to, actually

Comment: Good work, I did it implementing also "parentNode", because I only had the body id.

'<script type="text/javascript">
  document.querySelector('#bodyID').parentNode.lang = "IT-it";
</script>'

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can edit a HTML tag in JavaScript.

Without jQuery :

```
document.querySelector('#elementId').lang = 'it';
```

With jQuery :

```
$('#elementId').attr('lang', 'it');
```

If you need to select a specific tag and you don't know how to, just use the Developer Tools of your browser (Ctrl + Maj + I). Then, you can find the tag and copy the unique CSS selector of the it by :

> Right click on the tag you want in the tool > Copy > Copy selector/CSS selector

The last item changes depending on your browser.